pyarrow chunkedarray get items at given indices
Say I have
In [3]: import pyarrow as pa

In [4]: ca = pa.chunked_array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

I'd like to extract elements [1, 4, 2] and end up with
<pyarrow.lib.Int64Array object at 0x7f6eb43c2d40>
[
  2,
  5,
  3
]

as if I was doing NumPy-style indexing

Use the take function
import pyarrow as pa
ca = pa.chunked_array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
subset = ca.take([1, 2, 3])

